# Create React Native App Change iOS Device

Tags: react-native, create-react-native-app

I am trying to launch a react native app, created with create-react-native-app, however I do not want it to launch in the iPhone 6.

How can I change the device? All docs I can find give advice on apps created with react-native init.

`npm run ios -- --simulator="iPhone X"` does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a device by using

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 5s"
```

Just enter the device ID you want and all should be merry. Worth noting there is no way to currently set/change the default.

Comment: Hey, that doesn't seem to work if I've created the app with create-react-native-app

Comment: run `xcrun simctl list devices`, is your desired device listed?